# Halfway translation in GNOME

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, language

I changed my GNOME's language from english to persian. Some parts are well translated, but some other not. For example most of numbers and some of apps' names.
This is output of `locale`:

```
LANG=fa_IR
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fa_IR"
LC_NUMERIC="fa_IR"
LC_TIME="fa_IR"
LC_COLLATE="fa_IR"
LC_MONETARY="fa_IR"
LC_MESSAGES="fa_IR"
LC_PAPER="fa_IR"
LC_NAME="fa_IR"
LC_ADDRESS="fa_IR"
LC_TELEPHONE="fa_IR"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fa_IR"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fa_IR"
LC_ALL=
```

I use debian 11 and Gnome 3.41.3. Photos:
[image: Gnome clocks]

[image: LibreOffice]

[image: Some other apps and folders]

Comment: Some apps are well translated, other not so much if at all. For LO, do you have `libreoffice-l10n-fa` installed? You could try translating the missing parts yourself and feed them back into the community. I think they would be well recceived.

Comment: @Bib I installed language packages of apps, but my main problem is numbers. I jad ubuntu before and I did not have any problem with the anguage.
UPDATE: I have `libreoffice-l10n-fa` but name of the application in shown in english.